# count row occurence and aggregate SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I did a query (pretty simple, with 4 columns x 100 000 rows) and there are redundancies (rows appear several times).
I'd like to add a column that counts the number of times each row appears, and then remove the duplicates. So I don't lose information by adding this "count" column, and in the mean time lighten the table by deleting duplicate rows.
For instance if I have this table:

| name | country | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| table | France | 12 |
| desk | Italy | 8 |
| table | France | 12 |
| desk | Italy | 8 |
| desk | Italy | 14 |
| desk | Italy | 8 |

And the output should be like:

| name | country | price | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table | France | 12 | 2 |
| desk | Italy | 8 | 3 |
| desk | Italy | 14 | 1 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you're using, provide some sample data, the query you're currently using, the sample output from that query, and your desired result. [ask]

Comment: yes, just added example and dbms used (mysql). I use it in an online editor for educational purposes

Answer (score 0):

To count how many occurrences of a record that appears in a table, you can use the `GROUP BY` command, this will count how many occurrences depending on what you want to group by.

For instance, if you `GROUP BY country` then it will count how many records were found for each country.

Example: `SELECT name, country, price, COUNT(*)  FROM tablename  GROUP BY name;`

You can read up on `GROUP BY` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: This is not valid SQL (it might run with some settings on MySQL, but it is still not valid). It would need `country` and `price` adding to the group by, otherwise the values returned for those two columns will be arbitrary and non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work for you:

```
select `name`, `country`, `price`, count(*) from MyTable
group by `name`, `country`, `price`
```